# How to depict the size/scale with grids in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, grid, figure

I have a figure that has 100 x 100 cells with associated length size of 20m x 100m for the total number of cells, respectively. I tried to plot the similar figure in Matlab, however, I could not plot the associated size i.e. 20m X 100m with the gridded data. I used the following code line to plot the gridded data in Matlab.

```
imagesc(variable)
colorbar
```

The Figure 1 plotted using Matlab looks like this:

**Figure 1:**
[image]

How can I depict the size/scale of 20m x 100m in Figure 1? By size/scale, I do not mean putting co-ordinates on X and Y axis. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `x` and `y` argument in [IMAGESC](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) like so:

```
imagesc([1 100],[1 20],variable)
axis equal
axis tight
```

Comment: I want to include the actual scale of 100:20 (x:y) on the Figure 2, just as Figure 1. I am not much concerned about showing x and y labels per se.

Comment: @S_H: sorry, forgot two lines in my solution.